# How Can I Fix this Node.js Login Authentication Page?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am working on a website with MongoDB, Node.js and Express (no React or Angular).  I have the user registration working fine.  But my login is not working and I cannot figure out why.  Below I post the relevant code:

index.js

```
/*
*   Login Existing User
*/
const loginController = require("./controllers/login")
app.get('/auth/login', loginController);
const loginUserController = require('./controllers/loginUser')
app.post('/users/login', loginUserController)
```

/controllers/login:

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
    res.render('login')
}
```

relevant portion of login.ejs (which is rendered due to preceding code):

```
<form action="/users/login" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="form-floating">
 <input class="form-control" id="username" type="text" placeholder="User Name" data-sb-validations="required" name = "username"/>
 <label for="title">Username</label>
 <div class="invalid-feedback" data-sb-feedback="title:required">A descriptive title is required.</div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-floating">
  <input class="form-control" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" data-sb-validations="required" name="password"/>
  <label for="name">Password</label>
  <div class="invalid-feedback" data-sb-feedback="name:required">Password required.</div>
  </div>
  <br />
<!-- This is what your users will see when there is-->
<!-- an error submitting the form-->
  <div class="d-none" id="submitErrorMessage"><div class="text-center text-danger mb-3">Error sending message!</div></div>
   <!-- Submit Button-->
   <button class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" id="submitButton" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

/controllers/loginUser:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const User = require('../models/User')

module.exports = (req,res) =>{
    const { username,password } = req.body
    
    User.findOne({username: username}, (error,user) => {        
        if(user){
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (error,same)=>{
                if(same){
                    req.session.userId = user._id
                    res.redirect('/')
                }
                else{
                    res.redirect('/auth/login')
                }
            })
        }
        else{
            console.log("/auth/login::",user)
            res.redirect('/auth/login')
        }
    })
}
```

I have used Postman and also just tested in Chrome and Firefox and it appears that the GET made to /auth/login appears to work.  I get there and I submit my form.  But instead of redirecting me to my index or landing page ("/"), it just sends me back to /users/login and, also, the website doesn't recognize that I am logged in.  Here is my code to trigger a Boolean if I am logged in:

```
global.loggedIn = null;

app.use("*", (req, res, next) => {
    loggedIn = req.session.userId;
    next()
});
```

Any thoughts/suggestions as to what I am doing wrong are appreciated.

Comment: I think the “ enctype="multipart/form-data"” is the error but either way did you log the response coming into the server ?

Comment: According to Postman the body contains the username and password json.  Is that what u mean?  Maybe I don't understand your question?